# Write huge POJO to file with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, streamwriter

I want to write a POJO to a file. I do simple

```
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(this.DATA, null, 2))
```

I was working until the variable `this.DATA` was not too big, but now I am getting.

> (node:12954) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid string length
>       at Object.stringify ()

I guess I have run in to this: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/14170

Is there a way to write a huge POJO from memory to a file with formatting like this:

```
JSON.stringify(this.DATA, null, 2)
```